# Data from a form won't pass into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I've successfully managed to create a php login form using various tutorials online. But now I want the user to be able to add a device to their account if you will which will be linked to their user ID that was given to them on sign up to the website.

I created a second table to hold the data on the devices which includes its own auto increment ID for that device, this is the primary key. The table also has another column for the user IDs that is a foreign key. I want to show which user has that particular device. I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I can't seem to get this particular form to submit the data to the MySQL database like I previously did with the sign up form.

I keep the database details in a separate folder and refer back to it when it's needed:

```
<?php

$servername = "xxx";
$dBUsername = "xxx";
$dBPassword = "xxx";
$dBName = "xxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Then this is my form for the user, once logged in, to add a new device (tracker) to their account:

```
<?php
  require "header.php";
 ?>

<main>
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
      echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Log Out</button>
      </form>';

      echo '<form action="includes/trackerSub.inc.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="trackeruid" placeholder="Tracker Name...">
              <input type="text" name="trackerType" placeholder="Tracker Type...">
              <button type="submit" name="tracker-submit">Submit</button>
            </form>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail...">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
        <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>';
    }
   ?>
</main>


 <?php
   require "footer.php"
  ?>
```

In the require header.php I keep the session_start():

```
<?php
  session_start();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Mother Bird</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
```

Then finally in trackerSub.inc.php which is the form action I have:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) {

  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $trackeruid = $_POST['trackeruid'];
  $trackerType = $_POST['trackerType'];
  $idUser = $_SESSION['userId'];

if (empty($trackeruid) || empty($trackerType)) {
  header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=emptyfields");
}
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $trackeruid)) {
  header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=invalidtrackeruid");
  exit();
}
else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO trackers (idUsers, uidTracker, trackerType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $idUser, $trackeruid, $trackerType);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header("Location: ../dashboard.php?signup=success");
    exit();
  }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);

}
else {
  header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
  exit();
}
```

[The trackers table in phpMyAdmin looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVvnB.png)

[The users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJI4f.png)

Any help would be really appreciated, as I said earlier I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I've spent the last two days trying to fix these and researching but I can't quite see where I went wrong.

Many thanks,
Madamot

Comment: Where's the call to session_start() within the header file?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Apologies I probably should've included that, I've edited the post to include the header.php code. the call to session_start() is right at the top of the document above the <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: im not clear on what happens currently once you submit the form? do you land on "trackerSub.inc.php" ?

Comment: @tim At the time being nothing, I just want the data they submit to go in to the database. Eventually I want to have longitude and latitude data linked to each tracker which will be displayed below using the google maps API when the user logs in. And they have the option to add more trackers to their account if they wish, which is what the form is for. And obviously each user will have different trackers so when they log in I want them to only be able to see their trackers.

Comment: i understand what you want, but i dont know what your currently seeing, according to your code you should be redirected from "trackerSub.inc.php" do dashboard.php with various variables,  are you saying that isent happening?

Comment: @tim Yeah so when I submit the form trackerSub.inc.php is just pure php and mysql code which is supposed to submit the data to the database and then redirect me back to the dashboard.php. This is exactly what happens I end up back there at dashboard.php but when I check phpMyAdmin the data entered into the form isn't in the database for some reason?

Comment: you have 5 redirects to the dashboard, which one is actually being triggered?

Comment: @tim the header("Location: ../dashboard.php?signup=success"); so none of the error handlers are triggered and in theory it all seems to have worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this let me know if its works

```
if(isset($_POST['tracker-submit']))
 {

      require 'dbh.inc.php';

      $trackeruid = $_POST['trackeruid'];
      $trackerType = $_POST['trackerType'];
      $idUser = $_SESSION['userId'];

      if(empty($trackeruid) || empty($trackerType)) 
      {
        header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=emptyfields");
      }
      else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $trackeruid))
      {
        header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=invalidtrackeruid");
        exit();
      }
      else 
      {
                 $sql = "INSERT INTO trackers (idUsers, uidTracker, trackerType) VALUES ('$idUser', '$trackeruid', '$trackerType')";
                 $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                if(!$res)
                 {
                  header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=sqlerror");
                   exit();
                 }
              else
                {

                  header("Location: ../dashboard.php?signup=success");
                  exit();
                }
      }

      mysqli_close($conn);

}
else {
 header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
 exit();
   }
```

Comment: if still not work then try to check whether the values are POST successfully  from the form or not. best way to echo $_POST['trackeruid'], $_POST['trackerType'], $_SESSION['userId'] on the same page. when you press $_POST['tracker-submit'] to check every values retrive successfully or not.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't work. I did what you suggested in the comment, the values of POST are successful:  
`echo $_SESSION['userId'] . "<br>";
    if (isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) {
      if (empty($_POST['trackeruid'])) {
        echo "it is empty";
      }
      else {
        echo $_POST['trackeruid'] . "<br>";
      }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) {
      if (empty($_POST['trackerType'])) {
        echo "it is empty";
      }
      else {
        echo $_POST['trackerType'] . "<br>";
      }
    }` 
[Result](https://imgur.com/gallery/Ty3GE05)

Comment: Hmm that's weared. Remove all the If conditions and simple add add the insert query inside if(isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) then try. If it's not successful inserted then values are not reached inside the elseif ladder. Or there is a database Connection problem.

Comment: [Values put into the form are still echoed out](https://imgur.com/a/odgBy3e).

`if (isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) {
      echo $_POST['trackeruid'] . "<br>";
      echo $_POST['trackerType'] . "<br>";
      echo $_SESSION['userId'] . "<br>";
    }`. 

I dont think there is a connection problem since the signup and login forms work

Comment: No, I said put the insert SQL insert query inside if (isset($_POST['tracker-submit'])) and hit button.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['tracker-submit']))
 { 
require 'dbh.inc.php'; 
$trackeruid = $_POST['trackeruid'];
 $trackerType = $_POST['trackerType']; 
$idUser = $_SESSION['userId']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO trackers(idUsers, uidTracker, trackerType) VALUES('$idUser', '$trackeruid', '$trackerType')"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
if(!$res) 
{ 
header("Location: ../dashboard.php?error=sqlerror"); exit();
 } 
else {
 header("Location: ../dashboard.php?signup=success"); exit();
}}

Comment: Oh I see sorry my mistake!! Unfortunately that still isn't working. What could be the reason as to why the $_POST values aren't reaching the trackerSub.inc.php file?